# Отправка zip файлов на сервер c#

Tags: c#, парсер, сервер, pdf, restsharp

имеется файл pdf, в нем на каждой странице имеется по одной квитанции. Необходимо разделить этот pdf файл постранично, дать каждому новому файлу имя - взять данные из общего pdf - файла (период и лицевой счет). Затем по 50 новых pdf файлов упаковать в архивы, и архивы отправить на сервер. Я еще начинающий специалист, для парсинга pdf использовала одну библиотеку, для разделения pdf -  другую. В идеале бы использовать одну, но не знаю, как. Возникла проблема, файлы не уходят на сервер. Также существует проблема при их открытии. Переданных архив не открывается. Помогите, пожалуйста. Буду благодарна.

```
    private void ExchangeBillsPDF(string path)
    {
       
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
        File.Copy(path, Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), filename), true);

        string resultPdfText = "";

        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();

        PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(filename, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader pdfr = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(filename);

        Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
        Document.Compress = true;
        doc.Open();
        for (int i = 1; i <= pdfr.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            resultPdfText += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfr, i);
        }

        int j = 0;
        int chet = 0;
        int arhShet = 1;
        string[] sourceText = resultPdfText.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        for (int i = 0; i < sourceText.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (sourceText[i].Contains("ИЗВЕЩЕНИЕ"))
            {
                i += 4;
                string dateStr = sourceText[i].Substring(sourceText[i].IndexOf("ПЕРИОД") + 7);

                DateTime date = default;
                date = DateTime.Parse(dateStr);

                i++;
                string ls = sourceText[i].Trim();
               

                PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument();

                outputDocument.Version = inputDocument.Version;

                outputDocument.Info.Title = String.Format("Page {0} of {1}", j + 1, inputDocument.Info.Title);
                outputDocument.Info.Creator = inputDocument.Info.Creator;

                outputDocument.AddPage(inputDocument.Pages[j]);
                string pdfName = String.Format("Bills_keyField_{0}{1}.pdf", ls, date.ToString("Myyyy"));
                outputDocument.Save(pdfName);
                zip.AddFile(pdfName);

                chet++;
                j++;
                if (chet == 50 || inputDocument.Pages.Count == j)
                {
                    string zipName = $@"arhive_{arhShet}.zip";
                    zip.Save(zipName);


                    string APIKey = _taskInfo.ApiKey;
                    string dataType = "ZIP";
                    string dbFileName = _taskInfo.Name;

                    SendData(dbFileName, APIKey, dataType, zipName);

                    zip = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile();
                    chet = 0;
                    arhShet++;
                }

            }

        }

    }

    public static async Task<bool> SendData(string baseName, string apiKey, string dataType, string zipToUpload)
    {
       
        string fileName = $"{zipToUpload}";
        RestClient client = new RestClient("https://jul.ashx");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment;filename={fileName}");
        request.AddHeader("ImportOptions", $"basename={baseName};apikey={apiKey}");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic AaaaA");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip");
        string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(zipToUpload);

        request.AddParameter("application/zip", fileContent, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);

        return response.IsSuccessful;


    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Один пост - один вопрос. Выберу тот, что про отправку, ответ ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в `SendData`:

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(zipToUpload);
```

ZIP архив - это двоичный файл, а не текстовый.

Надо

```
byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(zipToUpload);
```

В остальном все то же самое.

---

Так же присутствует ошибка при вызове отправки, метод должен быть асинхронным.

```
private async Task ExchangeBillsPDFAsync(string path)
{
    // ...
    bool success = await SendData(dbFileName, APIKey, dataType, zipName);
    // ...
}
```

[Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

---

Бонусом подскажу, что я бы использовал `HttpClient` вместо RestSharp. Суть та же, только можно избавиться от лишней библиотеки.

```
private static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

public static async Task<bool> SendDataAsync(string baseName, string apiKey, string dataType, string zipToUpload)
{
    using var fs = File.OpenRead(zipToUpload);
    using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://jul.ashx")
    {
        Content = new StreamContent(fs)
    };
    request.Headers.Add("ImportOptions", $"basename={baseName};apikey={apiKey}");
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "aaaaA");
    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
    request.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = zipToUpload };

    using var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
    // string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // на случай если ответ станет важен
    return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
}
```

Comment: а если отправлять не ZIP - архив, а pdf - файлы ? Тогда следует использовать это string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(zipToUpload); ?

Comment: @jul я вас расстрою, но PDF - это тоже не текстовый файл. Текстовый файл - это файл, содержащий только текст в какой-то кодировке. Такой файл можно открыть с помощью простого блокнота или Notepad++. Например html, txt или log.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!