# Ошибка 401 при отправки файлов WebClient

Tags: c#, файлы, webclient

Использую данный код для отправки zip - файлов на сервер. Получаю ошибку "Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (401) Несанкционированный." Необходима авторизация. Как при использовании WebClient указать данные для авторизации ?

```
private void SendFile(string fileName)
        {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;                
                string url = $"http://import.ashx";

                var result = wc.UploadFile(url, fileName);
                string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
                if (message.Trim() != "successfully processed items: 1 <br />")
                {
                    Log.Error(message);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Info("Отправлен");                  
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `WebClient` является устаревшим компонентом в C# языке (об этом сказано в документации), заменой ему является современный `HttpClient`. Касательно авторизации - вы ведь понимаете, что их сотня видов? Где-то нужна Cookie с ключом, где-то заголовок (которых несколько видов), где-то свои механизмы, это все зависит от сервера, о котором мы ничего не знаем, из-за чего и ответить на ваш вопрос почти нереально (если только гадать).

Comment: Вы же нормально использовали RestSharp, и заголовки были на месте, что произошло? И да, `WebClient` - старьё.

Comment: да, тот код работает хорошо, проверяли другие методы. Спасибо за ответы, поняли насчет WebClient

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1376371/373567 добавил вам пример `HttpClient` в прошлый ответ.